# fotorama jQuery plugin and ALT tags

Tags: fotorama

In Canada, we have a new law that you must have ALT tags for images but when my page loads, the fotorama plug-in seems to remove them from the code. Is there a workaround or something that I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in a same situation like you are now.

*Fotorama* seems to discard and totally remove *alt* and *title* tags as not necessary in its purposes.
You need to raise a *bug* in its *bug tracking system* so that in its future releases it may include this *tag* particularly and all the other *HTML* standard *tags* that blindfully it discards.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to let you(other) know. Issue with stripping "Alt", "Title" attributes have been fixed (I really like this dll, and this issue used to freak me out), I asked owner to pull fix.

Answer (score -1):

In order to show the Alt and Title in image use the image with in DIV.

Use  :

```
<div><img  src="http://www.example.com/image.png" alt="My Alt" title="My Title"/></div>
```

Instead of :

```
<img  src="http://www.example.com/image.png" alt="My Alt" title="My Title"/>
```